# How to deserialize XML attribute of type long to UTC DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, utc, xmlserializer

Following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793921/deserialise-xml-file-to-net-object/4794616#4794616) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015971/is-this-an-inefficient-way-to-parse-xml/4016454#4016454), I've decided to use [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) as the most simple way to parse XML.

But I want some **refinements:**

1. My top request is changing `MyRoot.Time` type from `long` to `DateTime`. It can be achieve easily by code using [`DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletimeutc.aspx) or [`new DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx), but can it be done directly by the XmlSerializer?
2. Can I change `MyRoot.Children` type into something more complex like `Dictionary<string,Tuple<int,ChildState>>`?

**My XML:**

```
<Root timeUTC="129428675154617102">
    <Child key="AAA" value="10" state="OK" />
    <Child key="BBB" value="20" state="ERROR" />
    <Child key="CCC" value="30" state="OK" />
</Root>
```

**My classes:**

```
[XmlRoot]
[XmlType("Root")]
public class MyRoot
{
    [XmlAttribute("timeUTC")]
    public long Time { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Child")]
    public MyChild[] Children{ get; set; }
}

[XmlType("Child")]
public class MyChild
{
    [XmlAttribute("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("state")]
    public ChildState State { get; set; }
}

public enum ChildState
{
    OK,
    BAD,
}
```

Comment: I saved myself from a tumbleweed. Do you, dear community, have a better answer for #1 and any answer on #2? or, should I accept my own answer?

Comment: The XML Serializer has none of the capabilities you're looking for. If you want a simple way to handle XML, look at LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is still the same: XmlSerializer does not offer such customization. You can use the same technique for the other feature, however, it is a bit longer… (XmlSerializer is, as you said, *simple*, you should consider different serializers for such custom stuff.)

```
[XmlRoot]
[XmlType("Root")]
public class MyRoot
{
    // ...

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, ChildState>> Children { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Child")]
    public MyChild[] ChildrenRaw
    {
        get
        {
            return Children.Select(c => new MyChild { Key = c.Key, Value = c.Value.Item1, State = c.Value.Item2 }).ToArray();
        }

        set
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, ChildState>>(value.Length);
            foreach(var item in value)
            {
                result.Add(item.Key, new Tuple<int, ChildState>(item.Value, item.State));
            }
            Children = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about `XmlIgnore`.

Comment: BTW, ToDictionary: `value.ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => new Tuple(c.Value, c.State));`

Answer (score 1):

I dig up and found this method in a [two years old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523245/deserialization-error-the-xml-element-name-from-namespace-is-already-presen/523495#523495) by [Marc Gravell♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell):

```
public class MyChild
{
    //...

    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("timeUTC")]
    [Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public long TimeInt64 
    {
        get { return Date.ToFileTimeUtc(); }
        set { Date = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(value); }
    }
}
```

This is a fair method that solve question #1. Still no answer on #2.